# Google Play Developer Console: Supported devices missing 7" tablets for xlarge screens

Tags: android, google-play, android-screen-support

I'm publishing my app on Google Play. The app is designed only to run on tablets from 7". I read in the SDK docs that 7" are considered xlarge screens. My manifest reads:

```
 <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false" />
```

However, under supported devices in the Developer console I only see tablets from 8.8", all 7" are missing.

How can I do to support 7" tablets as well, but no smaller screen devices?

[image]

Comment: "I read in the SDK docs that 7" are considered xlarge screens" -- no, `-xlarge` does not kick in until closer to 10", though it will vary by device manufacturer. "How can I do to support 7" tablets as well, but no smaller screen devices?" -- AFAIK, the Play Store is still not honoring `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp`. You can accept `-large` devices, and adjust your UI to work well on screens starting at 5".

Comment: thanks for the quick & concise answer!